# SELECT FROM (lv_tablename) error: the output table is too small

Tags: dynamic, abap, opensql

I have an ABAP class method, say, select_something. select_something has an exporting parameter, say, et_result. et_result is of type standard table because the type of et_result cannot be determined until runtime.

The method sometimes gives a short dump saying **With ABAP/4 Open SQL array select, the output table is too small** at "**select * into table et_result from (lv_tablename) where...**"

Error analysis:

**......in this particular case, the database table is 3806 bytes wide, but the internal table is only 70 bytes wide.**

I tried "any table" too and the error is the same.

Answer (score 3):

You could return a data reference. Your query will no longer fail, and you can assign the data to a correctly typed field symbol afterwards.

```
" Definition
class-methods select_all
  importing
    !tabname type string
  returning
    value(results) type ref to data.


...
...


" Implementation
method select_all.
  data dref type ref to data.
  create data dref type standard table of (tabname).
  field-symbols <tab> type any table.
  assign dref->* to <tab>.
  select * from (tabname) into table <tab>.
  get reference of <tab> into results.
endmethod.
```

Also, I agree with @vwegert that dynamic queries (and programming for that matter) should be avoided when possible.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do looks horribly wrong on many levels. NEVER use SELECT FROM (whatever) unless someone points a gun at your head AND the door is locked tight. You'll loose every kind of static error checking the system might be able to provide you with. For example, the compiler will no longer be able to tell you "Hey, that table you're reading from is 3806 bytes wide." It simply can't tell, even if you use constants. You'll find that out the hard way, producing short dumps, especially when switching between unicode and NUC systems, quite likely some in production systems. No fun.

(Actually there are a few - very very VERY few - good uses for dynamic table names in the SELECT statement. I need them about once every two to three years, and I code quite a lot weird stuff. Just avoid them wherever you can, even at the cost of writing more code. It's just not worth the trouble fixing broken stuff later.)

Then, changing the generic **formal** parameter type does not do anything to the type of the **actual** parameter. If you pass a STANRDARD TABLE OF mandt WITH DEFAULT KEY to your method, that table will have lines of 3 characters. It will be a STANDARD TABLE, and as such, it will also be an ANY TABLE, and that's about it. You can twist the generic types anywhere you like, there's no way to enforce correctness using generic types the way you use them. It's up to the caller to make sure that all the right types are used. That's a bad way to fly.

Comment: What is the right way for "select * from zxx table where field1='something'"?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I agree with vwegert's response, try to avoid dynamic sql selections if you can

That said, check the short dump. If the error is an exception class, you can wrap the SELECT statement in a try/catch block and at least stop it from dumping.

You can also try "`INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE et_result`". If ET_RESULT is dynamic, you might have to cast it into the proper structure using RTTS. [This](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_731/en/abendynamic_sql_abexa.htm) might give you some ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't agree more to vwegert, but if there is absolutely no other way (and there usually is) of performing your task than using dynamic select statements and dynamically typed parameters, do some checks on the type of the table and the parameter at runtime.

Use CL_ABAP_TYPEDESCR and its subclasses to do so.

This way, you can handle errors at runtime without your program dumping,

But as vwegert said, this dynamic stuff is pure evil and will most certainly break at some point during runtime. Adding the necessary error handling will most likely be a lot more work and a lot harder than redesigning your code to none dynamic SQL and typed parameters